# Interaction between two binary variables in lavaan

Tags: interaction, structural-equation-modeling, categorical-encoding, lavaan

I have two binary variables (X1 and X2, coded 0/1) as predictors in a `growth` model in lavaan. I want to understand their individual contributions and their interactive influence on both intercept and slope. I believe there is no way for me to run the interaction in the lavaan model syntax, so I have created an interaction term (INT=X1*X2).

```
  # intercept and slope
    i =~ 1*G3_Theta_Read + 1*G6_Theta_Read + 1*G10_Theta_Literacy
    s =~ 0*G3_Theta_Read + 3*G6_Theta_Read + 7*G10_Theta_Literacy 

  # regressions
    i ~ X1 + X2 + INT
    s ~ X1 + X2 + INT '
```

This may be a rudimentary question, but I am wondering if there is a collinearity problem if X1=1, X2=1, and INT=1. Do I need to create new variables that are mutually exclusive, i.e.:

- X1_no_X2 (X1=1, X2=0)
- X2_no_X1 (X1=0, X2=1)
- neither (X1=0, X2=0)
- both (INT) (X1=1, X2=1)

Or is it ok just to have X1, X2, and INT all coded as 0/1, even though there will be overlap between all three when INT is coded 1?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update: I tried the : function (i.e., X1:X2) which appears to be working. I am actually trying to create a three-way interaction, but made original post only two-way because it was easier to articulate. If there is advice on manual coding of interaction term for three binary indicators, relating to the above concerns about collinearity, I would appreciate it!

Comment: Yes, the colon operator works for a 2-way interaction, but not higher-order interactions.  So you are better off creating the product terms as new variables, then including those in your syntax.

Comment: Thanks Terrence! If the interaction is coded manually (product term INT), do I run as    "i ~ X1 + X2 + INT" (potential collinearity problem?) 

...or do I run as "i ~X1_no_X2  +  X2_no_X1  +  neither + INT"? The latter involves recoding into four new variables (please see bullets above).

Comment: Four dummy codes to represent 4 groups would be multicollinear (any variable equals 1 minus the sum of the remaining 3 dummy codes).  You should do the same thing you do in an OLS regression model.

Comment: Thank you very much!